# Quickly doesn't import Glib

Tags: quickly, programming, glib

I'm having a little problem with Quickly. It won't import Glib, as I am relatively new to programming, with only a few weeks of coding under my belt, I've decided to try using Quickly following the Quickly tutorial to start me off, as presently I'm learning Java and XML for Android app programming and find it very interesting. Problem is, I have absolutely no idea what to do or what the error actually means, is there anyone out there who could help me out?

This the error I get when I try to run it through the terminal:

```
ERROR:root:Could not find any typelib for Glib
\Traceback (most recent call last):

File "bin/jokky", line 32, in module

  import jokky

 File "/home/abunujum/Quickly/jokky/jokky/__init__.py", line 14, in module

 from jokky import JokkyWindow

File "/home/abunujum/Quickly/jokky/jokky/JokkyWindow.py", line 18, in module

from gi.repository import Glib # pylint: disable=E0611

ImportError: cannot import name Glib
```

And here is the code:

```
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.textdomain('jokky')

from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('jokky')

from jokky_lib import Window
from jokky.AboutJokkyDialog import AboutJokkyDialog
from jokky.PreferencesJokkyDialog import PreferencesJokkyDialog

from gi.repository import Glib # pylint: disable=E0611
import os


class JokkyWindow(Window):
    __gtype_name__ = "JokkyWindow"

    def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002

        """Set up the main window"""
        super(JokkyWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)

        self.AboutDialog = AboutJokkyDialog
        self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesJokkyDialog

        # Code for other initialization actions should be added here.
    def on_mnu_save_activate(self, widget, data=None):        
        #get the title for the note
        title = self.ui.entry1.get_text()                

        #get the string
        buff = self.ui.textview1.get_buffer()
        start_iter = buff.get_start_iter()
        end_iter = buff.get_end_iter()
        text = buff.get_text(start_iter, end_iter, True)

        #create the filename
        data_dir = Glib.get_user_data_dir()
        jokky_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, "jokky")
        filename = os.path.join(jokky_dir, title)

        #write the data
        Glib.mkdir_with_parents(jokky_dir, 0o700)
        Glib.file_set_contents(filename, text)
```

The code in the box is the majority of the code that I wrote

Sorry the Question so long, I need help using Quickly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `GLib`, not `Glib`. You made a typo, it's written with a capital `L`.